# Mongodb aggregation - get all last inserted group of docs based on time

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

a quick puzzle for anyone familiar with mongodb aggregation if you want. so we have a simple model for example:

```
const listingSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  img: {type: String},
  url: {type: String, required: true},
  price: {type: Number, default: 0},
  roomType: {type: String, required: true},
  nights: {type: Number, required: true},
  time: {type: Date, required: true, index: true},
});
```

i'm inserting an group of objects periodically and wanna query last added group, this can be simply described with current solution code:

```
const lastListings = async () => {
  const time = await Listing.find({}).sort({time: -1}).limit(1);
  return Listing.find({time: time.time});
}
```

but i don't like it as this can be done more elegant way with aggregation - just love this tool a lot and trying to understand it good. anybody got ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below aggregation :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  /** Sort on entire collection is not much preferrable */
  /** Group on 'time' field & push all matching docs to 'docs' array */
  { $group: { _id: "$time", docs: { $push: "$$ROOT" } } },
  /** Now there will significantly less documents, do a sorting on '_id' field (which is time) */
  { $sort: { _id: -1 } },
  /** limit to 1 doc (All latest inserted docs will be inside 'docs' array of this one doc ) */
  { $limit: 1 },
  /** unwind 'docs' array */
  { $unwind: "$docs" },
  /** Replace docs object as new root for each document in collection  */
  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$docs" } },
]);
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lLfxX06UZ6M)

**Note :** Have an index on `time` field.

Comment: wow, you just made my day man! thanks for such commenting and this outstanding playground i didn't know about. this info helps a lot to get even more solutions for my project i been breaking my head about cuz after that i needed to group it by nights and leave just docs with minimum price value for each 'nights' group, this playgtound will help a lot with research. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

With aggregation you can do this like:

```
db.getCollection('listings').aggregate([
    { $sort: {time: -1} },
    { $limit: 1 }
])
```

Comment: thanks, i could achieve this same result, and that's the problem as now we want to take this single element from returned array, take it's time and perform $match operation to get whole group returned.